# "Configure Web Deploy" menu missing from IIS 8 menu

Tags: iis, webdeploy

I have been trying to setup Web Deploy on my Windows 2012 server running IIS 8. I have installed Web Deploy using Platform installer but when I right click my website and select deploy, there is no option for `Configure Web Deploy Publishing` as various [documentation](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/gabe/how-to-install-webdeploy-on-windows-server-2012/) suggests.

[image]

Comment: Be ware !! Web Deploy 3.6 doesn't work with IIS 8.5.9600.16384 ...
after installation, server restart - the deploy menu doesn't appear in IIS manager console
Web Deploy 2.0 how ever doesn't suffer this issue Best Regards,

Comment: I am also facing the same issue on IIS 10. I installed web deploy 3.6 then tried 3.5 also.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I found [this posting](http://forums.iis.net/t/1200267.aspx) where the individual had the same problem. Turns out that he needed to install "Web Deploy 3.5 for Hosting Servers" on top of the other Web Deploy packages in web platform installer. Once I did this and restarted IIS the option became available.

Seems counter-intuitive to me since I am not a hosting provider and just wanted to host my application on my own server. I am not sure why the Web Deploy 3.5 package was not enough.

I had additional problems getting Web Deploy configured. This [article on Web Deploy error codes](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes) helped me troubleshoot the problem. Another [article on Configure the Web Deployment Handler](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/configure-the-web-deployment-handler) was essential in solving the permissions issue allowing the web deploy user to create directories and files.

Comment: I kept trying to install Web Deploy 3.5 for Hosting Services, and it would tell me it succeeded.  When I opened the web platform installer again and searched for it, it would say it wasn't installed.  I had to uninstall Web Deploy 3.6 through the control panel before it would successfully install 3.5 for hosting services.  Once done, problem solved.

Comment: I had the same experience as @silencedmessage. I had to remove Web Deploy 3.6  via add/remove programs, and then install Web Deploy 3.6 for Hosting Servers.

Comment: For me restarting the IIS Services Manager was the missing piece, no amount of refreshing, or restarting the server itself or the websites will update the management UI, you need to restart the program itself.

Answer (score 72):

For me the reinstall of **Web Deploy** didn't work. But I fixed it.

Go into the **Server Manager**, **Roles**, click on **IIS**, click on **Add Role Services**, check the **Management Service**. Close that out. Reopen **IIS Manager**, and voila the option is available!

For Windows2012 R2 server, options is in'Web Server (IIS)' -> 'Management Tools' –> 'Management Service'

P.S. Some additional steps could be required, as of @Gaui experience.
Afterwards go to **Programs and Features**, find **Web Deploy**, click **Change** and check/**install all** checkboxes/features.

Comment: This worked for me, but afterwards I had to go to "Programs and Features", find "Web Deploy", click "Change" and check/install all checkboxes/features.

Comment: @Gaui thanks for your feedback, i will add it to my post.

Comment: After adding all the components from the "Programs and Features" don't forget to close all IIS Manager sessions and open a fresh one.

Comment: On Windows2012 R2 server 'Management Service' is under 'Web Server (IIS)' -> 'Management Tools'

Comment: worked for me, the various add ins were disabled by default. thanks mate.

Comment: Thats the good one! After doing this the option was still missing... But then I went to the Control Panel and selected Repair on the Web Deploy 3.6 (with the IIS manager closed). When I started the IIS manager again, there it was! Thanks

Comment: For me, repair did nothing, so I assumed it was fine - I actually had to press Change to be able to go in and add the disabled features.

Comment: went into control panel to find all web deploy features were not installed by default. set all true flags and worked. seems like an oversight by MS. if you install it, you want the features, right? thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You need to install Management Service before you install Web Deploy. If you haven't uninstall Web Deploy and reinstall it and it should work.

Comment: Can confirm this.

Comment: Oddly enough, this seems to do the trick. You can do it through the Add Server Roles or Turn optional features on and off. Might as well install ASP.NET 4.x while you’re at it, if that’s what you’re deploying.

Answer (score 8):

UPDATED:
Follow these steps:

1. type programs and features (in the menu search box)
2. Go to WEB DEPLOY (install it from web platform installer in case you don't have it)
3. Select WEB DEPLOY and click the change option at the top
4. Check and install ALL options available
5. Wait to install and close/reopen IIS GUI
6. the options should appear when you right click over the site.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and installing "Web Deployment Tool 2.1" from the Web Platform installer fixed the issue.

Comment: Work for me, but not show to me "Configure WebDeploy Publishing" menu item.

Comment: Also restarting IIS but is is not enought... I closed IIS window and reopened it again and the Deploy menu with all subitems appeared.

Answer (score 2):

Installing "IIS Management Service" from Web platform would show up all the required items.

Answer (score 1):

[coad comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23552640/4058784) was the solution for me. I was using Web Deploy 3.6 on IIS 8.5. Removed 3.6 and install 3.5 and it worked.

> Be ware !! Web Deploy 3.6 doesn't work with IIS 8.5.9600.16384 ... after installation, server restart - the deploy menu doesn't appear in IIS manager console Web Deploy 2.0 how ever doesn't suffer this issue Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I kept on right clicking on the web application instead of web site.

One can have multiple web applications under a web site. There is also a sub menu in the context menu when you right click the web application but it is "missing" the item "Configure Web Deploy Publishing...". This is because you configure web deploy publishing for **web site** and not for **web application**.

So to sum it up

- **Web site** has this option
- **Web application** doesn't have it